# Crash when trying to load a file using Node's repl library

Tags: node.js, port, elm, read-eval-print-loop

I am getting a crash at the indicated point below when the code attempts to load a file.  The file contents are read and displayed on the console. But when the line

```
app.ports.receiveData.send(data.toString());
```

is (tried to) execute, the code crashes.  I've attached the error message below the code.  The JS code here is used to run some Elm code "headless".  The `app.ports...` function call is supposed send data back to the Elm app.  (The Elm Code is further down).

**JS CODE:**

```
const repl = require('repl');
const fs = require('fs')



// Link to Elm code
var Elm = require('./main').Elm;
var main = Elm.Tool.init();


// Eval function for the repl
function eval(cmd, _, _,  callback) {
  main.ports.put.subscribe(
    function putCallback (data) {
      main.ports.put.unsubscribe(putCallback)
      callback(null, data)
    }
  )
  main.ports.get.send(cmd)
}


main.ports.sendFileName.subscribe(function(data) {
  var path =  data
  // console.log(path)
  fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    console.log(data.toString())
    // Crash on next line !!!!
    app.ports.receiveData.send(data.toString());
  })
});


function myWriter(output) {
  return output
}

console.log("\nType 'h' for help\n")

repl.start({ prompt: '> ', eval: eval, writer: myWriter});
```

**Elm CODE**

Here are the parts the Elm code that are relevant.

1. This code is called when the user wants to load a file.

```
loadFileCmd : String -> Cmd msg
loadFileCmd fileName =
    sendFileName (E.string <| "./source/" ++ fileName)
```

2. These are the ports used to communicate with JS

```
port get : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
port put : String -> Cmd msg

port sendFileName : E.Value -> Cmd msg
port receiveData : (E.Value -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

The `get` port listens for commands the user gives to the repl and gives these commands to Elm to process.  The `put` port sends data that Elm computes to the repl.

The `sendFileName` port sends a file path to the repl.  The `receiveData` port listens for the file contents. (But we crash before this can happen).

3. Here are the subscriptions:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ =
    Sub.batch [ Command.get Input, Command.receiveData ReceiveFileContents ]
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
repl.js:573
      const lines = errStack.split(/(?<=\n)/);
                             ^

TypeError: errStack.split is not a function
    at Domain.debugDomainError (repl.js:573:30)
    at Domain.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Domain.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at Domain._errorHandler (domain.js:253:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (domain.js:156:29)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:164:29)
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the Elm code you are trying to run (or at least a cut-down version of it that reproduces the problem you describe)?

Comment: Yes, added a section in the question with the relevant parts of the Elm code.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd say there are other relevant parts too.  How is the application started?  Are you using `Browser.element`?  If so, how are you handling the view layer given that there is basically no view?  If you're not using `Browser.element`, how are you wiring up the subscriptions?  At the moment if I want to try to reproduce your problem, I have to guess at what these missing bits are.  It would be ideal if you could include enough Elm code to allow me to compile and run your code: it doesn't have to be your full app, just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'll see if I reduce the app to a very small demo so as to better isolate the problem.  On the Elm side, I am using `Platform.Worker`. Thank you so much for looking at this.

Comment: I've just noticed the line your code crashes on uses `app.ports` rather than `main.ports` as used elsewhere.  Is that the problem or just a transcription error?

Comment: Hi, I put a much slimmed-down version on GitHub at

https://github.com/jxxcarlson/elm-cli-load-file

The README explains how to compile and run.

Comment: The Elm file is src/Main.elm -- 117 lines (79 sloc)

Comment: I've taken a look at that code.  It has the same error I mentioned in my comment about `app.ports`, and when I fixed that, it appeared to work, in that I could load a file and read its contents.

Comment: That indeed is it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, the answer was to replace the line

```
app.ports.receiveData.send(data.toString());
```

with

```
main.ports.receiveData.send(data.toString());
```

as the Elm app is named `main`, not `app`.